# Dar click a un botón cada cierto tiempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero saber cómo hago para que las etiquetas **a** se ejecuten cada 5 segundos, las 3 tienen su id, cómo hago para que se ejecuten una por una el tiempo que yo quiera usando jquery o javascript?

ya he intentado con SetInterval pero no logre dar con el resultado, el codigo no lograr dar click a las etiquetas

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
#tags{
height: 100vh;
background-color: #ddd;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#tags div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
#point1{
background-color: #ff0;
}
#point2{
background-color: #ff8000;
}
#point3{
background-color: #000;
}
#point1, #point2, #point3{
display: none;
}
#point1:target, #point2:target, #point3:target{
display: block;
}
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3{
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tags">
<div id="point1"></div>
<div id="point2"></div>
<div id="point3"></div>

<a href="#point1" id="btn1">Color 1</a>
<a href="#point2" id="btn2">Color 2</a>
<a href="#point3" id="btn3">Color 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando jQuery podrías utilizar el método [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) que dispara el evento que quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
$('a').trigger('click');
```

Y para que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo usando `setInterval()` como bien mencionaste.

```js
// tiempo expresado en milisegundos
var tiempo = 5000;
// intervalo
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('#btn1').trigger('click');
  $('#btn2').trigger('click');
  $('#btn3').trigger('click');
}, tiempo);

// eventos click de las etiquetas <a>
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  console.log('clic en btn1');
});
$('#btn2').click(function() {
  console.log('clic en btn2');
});
$('#btn3').click(function() {
  console.log('clic en btn3');
});
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
#tags{
height: 100vh;
background-color: #ddd;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#tags div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
#point1{
background-color: #ff0;
}
#point2{
background-color: #ff8000;
}
#point3{
background-color: #000;
}
#point1, #point2, #point3{
display: none;
}
#point1:target, #point2:target, #point3:target{
display: block;
}
#btn1, #btn2, #btn3{
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
<div id="point1"></div>
<div id="point2"></div>
<div id="point3"></div>

<a href="#point1" id="btn1">Color 1</a>
<a href="#point2" id="btn2">Color 2</a>
<a href="#point3" id="btn3">Color 3</a>
</div>
```